# How to Force NOT receive data when submitting HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am making a form which will autosubmit when the page loads.It submits POST data to another domain, The problem is that when the  form is submitted, It automatically receives JSON data in php format from another domain which is automatically downloaded by my users. I want that my form should submit data but NOT receive response or if received should discard that not download that data.

`index.html`

```
 <form name="certform" id="contactForm" action="http://example.com/submit.php" Method="POST">


  <input type="hidden" name="VoteId" value="111AAA" />

  <input type="hidden" name="VoteName" value="Vote&#33;" />

  <input type="hidden" name="CheckedBox" value="3" />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />

</form>
```

When submitted it sends data but Also receives response and downloads it. This should not happen.

The Conditions are:

1. I dont have access to the other domain (example.com)
2. I have full access to my own server (PHP, Jquery, JS, HTML)
3. The Form should be submitted automatically
4. If the other domain (example.com) sends back data it should not be automatically downloaded in user's browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, you could use curl for this purpose, so that you'll send a POST, but after sending you could still manage what you have to do:

```
if(isset($_POST['request'])) {

    $url = 'http://example.com/submit.php';
    $fields = array(
        'VoteId' => $_POST['VoteId'],
        'VoteName' => $_POST['CheckedBox'],
        'CheckedBox' => $_POST['CheckedBox'],
    );
    $count = count($fields);
    $fields = http_build_query($fields);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, $count);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

?>

<form name="certform" id="contactForm" action="" Method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="VoteId" value="111AAA" />
    <input type="hidden" name="VoteName" value="Vote&#33;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="CheckedBox" value="3" />

    <input type="submit" name="request" value="Submit request" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Something like:

```
$.post("http://example.com/submit.php", {
    "VoteId": "111AAA",
    "VoteName": "Vote&#33;",
    "CheckedBox": "3"
});
```